# ¿Cómo cambiar el orden de las barras horizontales de un gráfico en ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo un gráfico de frecuencia de síntomas y lo ordené de mayor a menor frecuencia, pero necesito ordenarlo de menor a mayor para que en el gráfico las barras horizontales de la mayor frecuencia queden arriba y no abajo. En este caso en el eje y me gustaría que de arriba a abajo sea: Catarro nasal, tos paroxística, tos > 14 días, etc.

El código que usé fue el siguiente:

```
ggplot(data = sintomas, mapping = aes(x = reorder(sintomas, desc(cantidad)), y = cantidad)) + geom_bar (stat = "identity", fill = "#88DAEE") + labs(x="Síntoma", y="Frecuencia absoluta", title="Frecuencia absoluta de síntomas de coqueluche. Año 2023. Argentina." + theme_classic()+theme(plot.title=element_text(size=12, face='bold'), plot.caption = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0), axis.title = element_text(size=11, face="bold"), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1), legend.position = "top") + geom_text(mapping = aes(x = reorder(sintomas, desc(cantidad)), y = cantidad, label = cantidad), vjust = 0, hjust= -0.5, colour = "black", size =  3) + coord_flip()
```

El gráfico por el momento se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pruebacambiar `x = reorder(sintomas, desc(cantidad))` por `x = reorder(sintomas, cantidad)` es eso?